# Mechanics of Javascript Asynchronous execution

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

Can someone please explain the mechanics behind the asynchronous behavior of javascript, specifically when it comes to a .subscribe(), or provide a link that would help me understand what's really going on under the hood?

Everything appears to be single-threaded, then I run into situations that make it either multi-threaded, or seem multi-threaded, because I still can't shake this feeling I'm being fooled.

Everything seems to run perfectly synchronously, one instruction at a time, until I call .subscribe(). Then, suddenly, something happens - it returns immediately, and somehow the next outside function runs even though the subscription code has not yet. This feels asynchronous to me, how does the browser keep things straight - if not threads, can someone please explain the mechanics in play that is allowing this to occur?

I also notice something happens with debug stepping, I can't step in to the callback, I can only put a breakpoint within it. In what order should I really expect things to occur?

Comment: `subscribe()` saves the callback function in a data structure somewhere. When the relevant event occurs, it calls the function. It's similar to the way `addEventListener()` works in plain JavaScript.

Comment: @Barmar I never thought of approaching from how Event Listener behaves, I'll review that.

Comment: You don't need threads for asynchronous programming. An event loop will suffice. Regarding rxjs observables, they're built on native asynchronous primitives (event handlers, timeouts, the like), nothing multi-threaded there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Javascript itself runs single threaded unless you're talking about WebWorkers (in the browser) or WorkerThreads (in nodejs).

But, many functions you call or operations you initiate in Javascript can run separate from that single threaded nature of your Javascript.  For example, networking is all non-blocking and asynchronous.  That means that when you make a call to `fetch()` in the browser of `http.get()` in nodejs, you are initiating an http request and then the mechanics of making that request and receiving the response are done independent of your Javascript.  Here are some example steps:

1. You make a call to `fetch()` in the browser to make an http request to some other host.
2. The code behind fetch, sends out the http request and then immediately returns.
3. Your Javascript continues to execute (whatever you had on the lines of code immediately after the `fetch()` call will execute.
4. Sometime later, the response from the `fetch()` call arrives back on the network interface.  Some code (internal to the Javascript environment) and independent from your single thread of Javascript sees that there's incoming data to read from the http response.  When that code has gathered the http response, it inserts an event into the Javascript event queue.
5. When the single thread of Javascript has finished executing whatever event it was executing, it checks the event queue to see if there's anything else to do.  At some point, it will find the event that signified the completion of the previous `fetch()` call and there will be a callback function associated with that event.  It will call that callback which will resolve the promise associated with the `fetch()` call which will cause your own Javascript in the `.then()` handler for that promise to run and your Javascript will be presented the http response you were waiting for.

Because these non-blocking, asynchronous operations (such as networking, timers, disk I/O, etc...) all work in this same manner and can proceed independent of your Javascript execution, they can run in parallel with your Javascript execution and many of them can be in flight at the same time while your Javascript is doing other things.  This may sometimes give the appearance of multiple threads and there likely are some native code threads participating in some of this, though there is still only one thread of your Javascript (as long as we're not talking about WebWorkers or WorkerThreads).

The completion of these asynchronous operations is then synchronized with the single thread of Javascript via the event queue.  When they finish, they place an event in the event queue and when the single thread of Javascript finishes what it was last doing, it grabs the next event from the event queue and processes it (calling a Javascript callback).

> I also notice something happens with debug stepping, I can't step in to the callback, I can only put a breakpoint within it. In what order should I really expect things to occur?

This is because the callback isn't called synchronously.  When you step over the function that you passed a callback to, it executes that function and it returns.  Your callback is not yet called.  So, the debugger did exactly what you asked it to do.  It executed that function and that function returned.  The callback has not yet executed.  Your are correct that if you want to see the asynchronous callback execute, you need to place a breakpoint in it so when it does get called some time in the future, the debugger will then stop there and let you step further.  This is a complication of debugging asynchronous things, but you get used to it after awhile.

> Everything appears to be single-threaded, then I run into situations that make it either multi-threaded, or seem multi-threaded, because I still can't shake this feeling I'm being fooled.

This is because there can be many asynchronous operations in flight at the same time as they aren't running your Javascript while they are doing their thing.  So, there's still only one thread of Javascript, even though there are multiple asynchronous operations in flight.  Here's a code snippet:

```
console.log("starting...");
fetch(host1).then(result1 => { console.log(result1)});
fetch(host2).then(result2 => { console.log(result2)});
fetch(host3).then(result3 => { console.log(result3)});
fetch(host4).then(result4 => { console.log(result4)});
console.log("everything running...");
```

If you run this, you will see something like this in the console:

```
starting...
everything running...
result1
result2
result3
result4
```

Actually, the 4 results may be in any order relative to one another, but they will be after the first two lines of debug output.  In this case, you started four separate `fetch()` operations and they are running independent of your Javascript.  In fact, your Javascript is free to do other things while they run.  When they finish and when your Javascript isn't doing anything else, your four `.then()` handlers will each get called at the appropriate time.

When the networking behind each `fetch()` operation finishes, it will insert an event in the Javascript event queue and if your Javascript isn't doing anything at the time, the insertion of that event will wake it up and cause it to process that completion event.  If it was doing something at the time, then when it finishes that particular piece of Javascript and control returns back to the system, it will see there's an event waiting in the event queue and will process it, calling your Javascript callback associated with that event.

Comment: Thanks for this! So I think the toughest part of this for me, maybe was separating the "Script" part out of the concept. I guess the point is that it might execute line by line in a single threaded fashion, but based on your answer there's more going on than just executing the instructions under the cursor.

Comment: @DanChase - Yep, lots more going on when you "start" an asynchronous operation.  It then proceeds somewhat independently of your Javascript execution and the two merge back together via the event queue sometime in the future.

Comment: I wish I could +1 this again, coming back to it from my dashboard page I read your response again and it's extremely helpful.

Comment: @DanChase - Glad to be of help.  Understanding how the event loop handles multiple asynchronous operations is an important part of feeling comfortable with how nodejs works.

Answer (score 0):

Search for articles or videos on the “JavaScript Event Loop”.  You’ll find plenty of them. Probably go through a few of them and it will start to make sense (particularly the single-threaded aspect of it)

I found this one with a quick search, and it does a good, very high-level walkthrough.

[The JavaScript Event Loop explained](https://blog.carbonfive.com/the-javascript-event-loop-explained/)

The main impact of JavaScript single threading is that your code is never pre-emptively interrupted to execute code on another thread.

It may seem that some code is being skipped, but close attention to the syntax will show that what is being “skipped” is just a callback function or closure to be called at a time in the future (when it will be placed into the event queue and processed single-threadedly, itself).

Careful, it can be tricky to follow nested callbacks.

Probably also look into Promises and async /await (‘just syntactic convenience on the event loop, but can really help code readability)